# Sitecore 8.1 : Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField

Tags: azure, lucene, sitecore, sitecore-azure, sitecore8.1

We just upgraded to Sitecore 8.1  from 7.2. Search engine is Lucene and xDB disabled. The solution is hosted in ms azure cloud services Web Apps.

We noticed that the CMS CA is quiet slow. While looking at logs noticed a number of error logged below:

```
13876 2015:12:18 05:21:44 ERROR Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: _content for indexable: sitecore://web/{2E25F9D3-BBBF-4160-BAE1-1EE4E701BD9B}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Access to the path 'D:\App_Data\data\mediaIndexing\b3cd2fa1-9671-498f-9534-a94ad5a21923-Mypolicy.pdf' is denied.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemIFilterTextExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFields()
```

Could someone please suggest why sitecore is looking for Web forms for marketing index which we don't need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about WFFM index in your error - it only says that it cannot compute value of the `_content` field for `{2E25F9D3-BBBF-4160-BAE1-1EE4E701BD9B}` item.

It even tells you the reason - cannot access path on the drive. You should check access rights for the `D:\App_Data\data\mediaIndexing` directory and make sure it can be access by you application user.

Comment: ah, mediaIndexing directory was missing. Is this directory part of Sitecore? In other words should this have been created as part of installation?

Comment: If you have the correct permissions set up for your data folder then it should have been created. Check Network service permisisons. useful blog here - https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2015/03/30/pesky-file-system-permissions/

Comment: @Marek Musielak Unfortunately the issue still exists as somehow sitecore looks for media indexing folder under D:\app_data instead of D:\wwroot|app_data. Wonder where is this path defiend for mediaIndexingFolder

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Web Apps you should have a full access in the file system to the `webroot` and its descendants. Ensure the `MediaIndexingFolder` setting is not set to absolute path and does not point to outside of the `webroot` where the application lives.

By default, if the `MediaIndexingFolder` setting is not specified, it points to the `$(dataFolder)/mediaIndexing` path, where the `$(dataFolder)` must point to the `\App_Data` under the `webroot`.

Comment: We are using SC8.1, I don't see any MediaIndexingFolder folder anywhere. Also We have definitely updated the datafolder to be /app_data

Comment: And, interesting part here is that if I have specified /app_data then I'm expecting it to look at something like wwwroot/app_data/mediaindexing

Answer (score 0):

We recently had the same issue. Essentially, make sure that on an Azure WebApp the standard zzDataFolder.config file is used which contains:

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder">
  <patch:attribute name="value">D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data</patch:attribute>
</sc.variable>
```

Using the other config that is included (DataFolder.config, which sets it to "/data") or your own config file (pointing to anything other than the full drive path) will break the mediaIndexing folder path (even though all other parts of Sitecore which use App_Data like "diagnostics" or "MediaCache" work perfectly well with the "/data" setting).